# SQL EXTRACT returns HOUR_MINUTE without colon

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to format my timestamp date to get only hour with minutes from it. The problem is that the returned format is weird "825-2100" when it should be "8:25-21:00". So the output should be with colon but it is without.

This is the select I am doing:

```
CASE WHEN (TRUE) then CONCAT('Aeg ',EXTRACT(HOUR_MINUTE FROM fp.valid_from), '-', EXTRACT(HOUR_MINUTE FROM fp.valid_to) else 0 end,
```

Why I get format without colon?

Comment: That's just the way `EXTRACT` works. Try `DATE_FORMAT('%k:%i', fp.valid_from)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `format` if you want a string.  Also, all branches of the `CASE` should return a string (or `NULL`):

```
(CASE WHEN (TRUE) 
      THEN CONCAT('Aeg ', 
                  FORMAT(fp.valid_from, '%H:%i%'),
                  '-'
                  FORMAT(fp.valid_to, '%H:%i%')
                 )
      ELSE ''
 END)
```

Comment: This version gives the following `Aeg 20,190,831,210,000-20,200,215,220,000`